# Не корректно работает спойлер, как исправить?

Tags: html, javascript

Такая вот проблема ребята, я жму на этот спойлер, он расскрывается, а когда жму обратно, чтоб закрыть, название спойлера тоже самое стоит и когда эти действия выполняю с открытым "Просмотр кода элемента", вижу что появляются много ошибок, за каждое нажатие набивается ошибка.

```
 <div class="smallfont"><input type="button" value="Фотографии пользователя" class="input-button"
onclick="if
(this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display != '') {
 this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = ''; this.innerText = ''; this.value = 'Свернуть'; } else {

this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')   [0].style.display
 = 'none'; this.innerText = ''; this.value = 'Развернуть';
}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @eicto, только псевдокласс :checked не работает ниже IE9

Comment: @mountpoint туда ему и дорога :) но вроде есть полифилы всякие.

Answer (score 2):

Не надо в `onclick` всё это писать уж точно, а вообще это легко реализуется на css

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3E2HL/

HTML

```
<div class="spoiler">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
        <div class="title">Это спойлер</div>
        <div class="spoil">Конец немного предсказуем</div>
    </label>    
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="spoiler">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
        <div class="title">Это другой спойлер</div>
        <div class="spoil">Конец совсем не предсказуем</div>
    </label>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.spoil {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.spoiler > label > input {
    position: fixed;
    left: -100px;
    top: 0;
}
.spoiler > label >.title {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.spoiler > label > input:checked ~ .title {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.spoiler > label > input:checked ~ .spoil {
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```